# How to record the paths in shortest path algorithm (Floyd-Warshall)

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

My code to find the shortest path via the Floyd-Warshall algorithm is working, but what I need is to actually store the path that is taken, not just the minimum value/cost/distance.

Here is my code.

```
# import the vertices/distance matrix
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import gsheets_LH

m1 = np.asarray(gsheets_LH.rangestore)

# Store destinations
firstrow = m1[0, 1:]

# Store origens
firstcolumn = m1[:, 0]

# Delete first row from table (headers)
G = np.delete(m1, 0, 0)

# Delete column, leaving only numbers/values
G = np.delete(G, 0, 1)

# The number of origins
nV = len(G)

# Defining matrix to receive result
distance = list(map(lambda i: list(map(lambda j: j, i)), G))

# Algorithm implementation for Line Haul Distance/Time Optimization


def floyd_warshall(G):
    distance = list(map(lambda i: list(map(lambda j: j, i)), G))
    # Adding vertices individually
    for k in range(nV):
        for i in range(nV):
            for j in range(nV):
                distance[i][j] = min(
                    distance[i][j], distance[i][k] + distance[k][j])
```

I just want to store a matrix or some other way to return to me ALL the shortest paths between all nodes.

Any help?

Comment: The networkx library might be useful to you: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path

Comment: If you store a second nV x nV matrix for the path back, you should be able to follow it back. See the wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction

Comment: Thanks @Oliver Chen. Would that still work if the path is one that has more than one stop?